# Flutter, background fetch package not working, androidx incompatibility

Tags: flutter, background-fetch

I wanted to make some operations while the app was not running, so I decided to use the background fetch package.I followed the android setup step by step
This is part of my pubspec.yaml

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.16
  geolocator: ^5.1.1
  flutter_local_notifications: ^0.7.1+1
  shared_preferences: '0.5.6+3'
  background_fetch: '^0.5.1'
```

This is part of my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="firenzepuliziastrade.firenze_pulizia_strade">
    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <application
        tools:replace="android:label"
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="Firenze Pulizia Strade"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
```

This is part of my app/build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion


    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "firenzepuliziastrade.firenze_pulizia_strade"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

}


dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

This is part of my android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    ext {
        compileSdkVersion   = 28                // or higher
        targetSdkVersion    = 28                // or higher
        appCompatVersion    = "1.1.0"           // or higher
    }

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // [required] background_fetch
            url "${project(':background_fetch').projectDir}/libs"
        }
    }
}
```

This is my gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.enableR8=true
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

I tried even the additional step to enable the Headless mechanism even though I thought that it was not necessary since my flutter version is Flutter 1.12.13 and I created this project recently.
But all that said I could not make the app do some work while not running, it just worked while being in the background. So I thought that the reason was that I was launching the app in debug mode and I tried to launch it in release mode, but I got the following error:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on POT LX1 in release mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':path_provider:verifyReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     /home/nik/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/0a271e99b6771ad4a84318244d532fb7/core-1.0.0/res/values/values.xml:57:5-88:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

     /home/nik/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/0a271e99b6771ad4a84318244d532fb7/core-1.0.0/res/values/values.xml:57:5-88:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin background_fetch...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...
Finished with error: ProcessException: Permission denied
  Command: /home/nik/Desktop/Pulizia_Strade/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/background_fetch-0.5.6/android/gradlew -I=/home/nik/Desktop/Pulizia_Strade/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/aar_init_script.gradle -Pflutter-root=/home/nik/Desktop/Pulizia_Strade/flutter -Poutput-dir=/home/nik/Desktop/Pulizia_Strade/firenze_pulizia_strade/build/app -Pis-plugin=true -Ptarget-platform=android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 assembleAarRelease
```

I tried to create a new flutter project, specifying androidx, but it did notwork, I got the same error. Can someone help me, I really do not know what to do at this point...

Comment: Hi Niccolò, did you solve this?

Comment: no, unfortunately no

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your app is not compatible with AndroidX. So far you've done some troubleshooting but didn't get to make it work. Try to double check the [AndroidX Migration Guide](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/androidx-migration) if you haven't missed anything.

So far, you've already enabled the Jetifier by adding the following lines to `[project_folder]/android/app/gradle.properties`

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Now try to enable multidex by adding this line in the `defaultConfig` of `[project_folder]/app/build.gradle`

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Then upgrade gradle dependency in the `[project_folder]/android/build.gradle` file:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
```

Latest version used in flutter as specified [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle).

Next, make sure that all your packages in the `pubspec.yaml` are of the latest version.

Lastly, run `flutter clean` and rebuild your project.