# Getting Android resource linking failed after adding background_fetch to my project

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, release

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':background_fetch:verifyReleaseResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask$Action
> Android resource linking failed
> ERROR:/Users/musamaashraf/dev/projects/BuddyPark/build/background_fetch/intermediates/merged_res/release/values/values.xml:2520: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

  BUILD FAILED in 1m 41s
  Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          102.3s
  Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

This error appeared when I added the `background_fetch: ^1.1.1`. Appears to be an issue with the gradle I upgraded from 7.1.0 to 7.2.0 and then to 7.3.0.

Also added the other fixes that I could find.

`android/build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            // [required] background_fetch
            url "${project(':background_fetch').projectDir}/libs"
        }
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

`gradle.properties` file:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
android.jetifier.ignorelist=bcprov-jdk15on
```

Tried the fixes in this guide: [Flutter, background fetch package not working, androidx incompatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62900562/flutter-background-fetch-package-not-working-androidx-incompatibility)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced a similar issue, To fix the issue **I updated the android/build.gradle like**

[image]

I believe the life saver here is `appCompatVersion = "1.4.2"`

**And used the compile and traget sdk version in app/build.gradle like**

```
compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
```

Comment: For me apoCompatVersion = "1.3.0" -> Solved the issue. If I go above this it causes an error.